# Socket connection runs fine in stand alone "main(..)" class, but times out in servlet enviornment

Tags: java, windows, networking, servlets, operating-system

Let me explain the problem by a scenario :

1) User visit my page "www.proxy4html.com" , fills up the form:

```
            web-address: |www.google.co.in |
```

2) click submit.

3) Gets google home page with "www.proxy4html.com" in browser address bar.

Now to fetch the contents from web I am using **java.net.HttpURLConnection** (although to resolve this I have tried several other options too). The code works as expected if it runs stand alone

(i.e *while running through **public static void main(String..)..** thread, it fetched whatever the html is on given web address*).

But the same when runs under the **Servlet** environment it throws

**java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect**

Here is the code:

```
public void write(String urlString, PrintWriter writer) {
    URL url;
    try {
        url = new URL(urlString);
        HttpURLConnection huc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(false);
        huc.setConnectTimeout(15 * 1000 * 60);
        huc.setReadTimeout(15 * 1000 * 60);
        huc.setRequestMethod("GET");

        huc.connect();
        InputStream input = url.openStream();
        logger.info("got input stream");//I never reach here in servlet env :(              
        int i = 0;
        while((i = input.read()) != -1) {
            writer.write(i);
            System.out.print((char)i);
        }

        input.close();
    } catch (ConnectException e) {
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "", e);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

The code example given may not appear clean but point to be taken is that when the above method is invoked from Servlet passing a proper **URL** (and whatever outputstream), the connection is never made.

I am running all this on my tomcat which is on my local machine, which is in some corporate network (you may not want get any conclusion concerning firewall because same code is running under a p.s.v.main).

please help....

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** I tried somewhat same at home and it worked fine as expected. **I guess this question falls more into operation system domain rather than java.** So I will like to rephrase my question again:

- **Is operating system (Window 7) is somehow preventing tomcat to make Http requests?**
- **Is their any configuration under Window 7 that doesn't allow application to make Http Request other than browser?**
- **I have seen in times that Mozilla Firefox (which I am running from a directory which is copied instead of being installed i.e may not have admin privileges and doesn't have a window registry) never able to do regular update to itself.**

Comment: Are you using same set of jars in both scenarios

Comment: Yes I guess I am behind a proxy. I can see the proxy been set in Internet explorer, but I don't understand if this could be the reason as still the same code works inside public static void main(..) thread.

Comment: Yes I guess in some sense I using the same set of jars, if you carefully see the code I am just using servlet spec(which is a runtime dependency provided by tomcat) and java.net package. Hence I don't see much of the dependency from external jars.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you prefer to insist that this is not a firewall issue (as the same code runs well as a standalone Java program), but I'm willing to take a risk here.

If you're absolutely sure that the very same code is being run in both cases (standalone case, and Tomcat case), there still is a possibility that it's a firewall issue.

The built-in firewall in Windows 7 assigns outbound rules per process per port. Is it possible that your standalone program runs with a JVM that has been allowed outbound access, whereas your Tomcat server runs with a JVM that hasn't been allowed outbound access?

In other words, are you *absolutely* confident that your standalone program, and your Tomcat server, are being run by the very same JVM? Very same `java.exe`? Under Windows, it's possible that your standalone program is actually being run by `javaw.exe`.

(You didn't mention whether you tried to completely disable the firewall. If you can disable the firewall completely, I'd suggest you do so, for the purpose of troubleshooting)